# scroll into view. robotframework 'Browser' library with frames

Tags: robotframework

I've got a couple of 20 a 25 working now.

This is another one I can't get to working:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser  enable_presenter_mode=True
#Library    XML
#Library    Collections
#Library    String
#Library    DateTime

Documentation     Scroll into view
*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***
Extracting text
    Open Browser    https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/99999
    #sleep  3s
    Browser.Focus   css=iframe >>> input[id="textfield"]
    sleep  1s
    Type Text    css=iframe >>> input[id="textfield"]    Tosca
    #Fill Text    textfield    Tosca
    Click    id=submit
    sleep  3s   
    # used resources: https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/browser/how-to-work-with-iframes
```

The problem here is that It can't type in the section whilst it is not into view.
The weird thing is: I have seen it working once where it typed while the textarea was NOT even into view. But the problem is I closed that instance of VScode and I was not able to see how that was produced (very tricky) (but I **know** it is possible without being into view, yes strange)

Answer (score 0):

Looked much things up.

I think this is almost it:

```
Browser.Scroll To  css=iframe >>> input[id="textfield"]  vertical=top
```